# unable to export a video file from device in the background

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

i am using SDAVAssetExportSession to export a video file in the setup (video and audio) that i desire. everything works fine until i switch to background mode and i starting to get  AV Foundation error : AVErrorUnknown - 11800.

seems that apple's AVAssetExportSession does exactly that  (regard the app state) , but because it's not very customisable i can't really use it in this case.

any recommendations ?
until now i have been trying  (with no luck) to :
 1. open a background task .
2. create a strong refence  for the session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just turn on (in the project capabilities - > background mode setting) "audio and airplay"